# unboundId ldap limit search

Tags: java, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I must get 200 users from my ldap school but the problem is I can't get more than 200 users else i am getting exception :

```
 String filter = "uid=G26274";
 String[] arrayFilter = filter.split("=");
 Filter filters = Filter.createNOTFilter(Filter.createEqualityFilter(arrayFilter[0], arrayFilter[1]));
 SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(query, SearchScope.SUB, filters, getParameter);
 searchRequest.setSizeLimit(200);
 searchResult = this.conn.search(searchRequest);
```

I am using setSizeLimit function and i get the same result.

thank you

Comment: What is the exception? Why would you expect to get more than one user with uid=G26274?

Answer (score 1):

setSizeLimit is for getting smaller results and doesn't override server limit.

You need paging mode:

[see the answer with example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337036/how-can-c-sharp-override-ldap-server-limit-but-not-java)